# URL alias not working for costume content type page.tpl file

Tags: 7, path-aliases

I a created a template file (page--cusomtype.tpl.php) for a specific content type and a node of that content type. Also I'm using Path module for create alias.

When I view the node with node/[node-id], I can see it; 
when I use its path alias, I get a "page not found" error. So how to apply alias for node of that content type?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Using a custom template file doesn't influence getting a path alias for the node being created. Rather, are you sure you are using the correct path alias. Did you create the path alias manually, or do you have installed the Pathauto module?

Comment: If you're using pathauto you may need to update and re-generate the alias' go to url alias' in config & bulk update tab. You may also need to check that the Generate automatic URL alias for that content is ticked.